# java program not able to access another class from same package when compiled from command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have two classes in a package. One class contained two methods. I am calling these methods in second class. On compiling from command prompt its showing error on first class name. Its running fine on Intellij though.

package with 2 classes - test2.java, test1.java

on compiling test1.java on cmd i m getting below error:

```
root@a TagPackage]# javac -classpath "/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/*" Test1.java 
Test1.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Test2
location: class TagPackage.Test2
    Test2 s= newTest2();
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
package TagPackage;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Test2 {
public String getControlBlock(String url) throws IOException {
   xcv...
}

public void  validate(String url, String ResponseCB) throws 
IOException,  JSONException {
    xzq...
}
}
```

---

```
package TagPackage;

import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1 {

Test2 s = new Test2();

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Test1 a = new Test1();
    try {
        a.testMethod();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Testmethod 1 out");

}

    public void testMethod()throws IOException, JSONException {
        String url = "dsadas";
        String ResponseCB = s.getControlBlock(url);
        s.validateurl, ResponseCB);
        System.out.println("Testmethod 1 reached here123");
        System.out.println("Testmethod 1 out");
}
```

Comment: "package with 2 classes - main.java, test.java" you need to be precise, even if you are trying to create simple example. Public classes need to have same name as `.java` files, so inside `main.java` there can be `main` class, not `Main` class (Java is case sensitive).

Comment: i have changed the name to Test2, still same error. it is not recognizing the class file.

Comment: can you show us your sample code please?

Comment: Did you rename the main.java fiel to Main.java?

Comment: The error says, that it can't find class Main. It will look in file Main.java. Does that file exist in the same directory?

Comment: You need to compile the Test2 first and then Test1

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the compiler from the directory that *contains* TestPackage, and you therefore  also need to specify TestPackage/Test1.java as the file to compile.

This is all documented.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a new project with default package and save your class in it.It worked for me :)